# Logical OR not operating as expected

Tags: c99

I'm writing a helper function to check if the path entered by the user contains 2 chars less than the buffer over flow. I'm using fgets() for input so I know two things.

1. The very last index will contain a '\0' char (Null terminating char)
2. If the user enters more chars than my limit, a char that is neither '\n' or '\0' will be in the second to last index, for example: char a[n] were: n = 5 my limit will be at n = 3, I reserve 2 spaces 1 for new line char and by default the fgets() inserts '\0' at last index

case 1: user enters a valid path, where input chars < 3  ex: "a"

case 2: user enters a valid path, where input chars == 3 ex: "abc"

case 3: user enters an invalid path, where input chars > 3 ex: "abcd"

to my problem, I have this if statement:
if( a [n-2] != '\n' || a [n-2] !='\0' )

no matter the case, it will always enter the if block and I'm puzzled as to why. It should only enter for case 3.

I could change the way I check with a simple char count, where I loop through the string and count all char's except '\n' or '\0' but I'm convinced the way I wrote it should work and I'm inclined to figure out why it doesn't before I try something else.

I've include the functions as they are called from top down. the if statement in question is the second if statement inside of check_file_name

```
const unsinged int file_name_size = 5;

int main(){
    char file[file_name_size] = {'\0'};
    get_file_name(file);
}

void get_file_name(char file_name[file_name_size]){

int is_valid = 1;

do {
    puts("Please enter the relative path");
    fgets(file_name, file_name_size, stdin);
    is_valid = check_file_name(file_name, is_valid);
} while(is_valid > 0);
}

int check_file_name(char file_name[file_name_size], int is_valid){

if(file_name[0] == '\n') {
    puts("Error: a file path must be provided, you entered nothing. Please enter the relative path");
}

if(file_name[file_name_size - 2] != '\n' || file_name[file_name_size - 2] != '\0') {
    puts("Error: the file path provided is too large.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

else {
    is_valid = 0;
}

return is_valid;
}
```

like I said above only case 3 should trigger the if but it always is triggered, even if I enter nothing. Here's the real bugger, if you remove the || and test each side of the || independently, it works as expected. Only in combination does it stop producing the correct result. Thanks in advance for any help and I apologize for any formatting or any stack over flow faux pas's. This is my fist post and I'm in a bit of a rush.

I think I've actually spotted the problem with my if statement. I was under the impression that only one side of the if statement needed to be flagged as false and it would skip. I forgot that both conditions would have to evaluate to false in order for it to not enter the block. For example: using case 2 as my test were a[n] = "abc\n"

a[3] = '\n'

does '\n' != '\n' false (I thought it would skip here however it evaluates other side too)

does '\n' != '\0' true (we enter the block, whoops)

sorry for rookie mistake and thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger and examining your variables to ensure that your assumptions are correct?

Comment: `a [n-2] != '\n' || a [n-2] !='\0'` is *always true*.  `a[n-2]` would have to simultaneously be equal to a newline and to a null character for this expression to be false.

Comment: @dandan78 I'm using xcode's debugger, however I'm not aware if it can show me what side of the OR is being flagged to true and entering the block.

Comment: @jasonharper I think you've spotted the problem. What I wanted the code to achieve in plain english is: "if at the second to last index, there is any char besides  '\n' or a '\0' then enter the block, otherwise skip." how would I rewrite it?

Comment: That would simply be `&&` instead of `||`.  "The character is not a newline, *and* it's not a null".

Comment: @jasonharper yup, thanks for pointing that out, rookie mistake I'm gonna archive/close this post

Comment: Doesn't somebody want to post an answer?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm going to add a summary at the end and answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Don't forget about De Morgan's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

```
if(file_name[file_name_size - 2] != '\n' && file_name[file_name_size] != '\0')
```

Because I negated the conditions, I also needed to negate the operator. Thus I needed to use && instead of ||

```
!(a || b) != !a || !b

!(a || b) == !a && !b
```